# php paypal sandbox dynamic list

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I am trying to make paypal button by using sandbox with multiple products.
When I add a product on shopping cart and press paypal button, it works fine.
However, if I make two or three products on shopping cart and press the button,
it comes up the message, 'Your shopping cart is empty'. 
I think that problem had in dynamic list.
Could you give me some help? dynamic list is using foreach statement. Honestly, other codes work fine which is in this foreach statement. Please help me. thanks.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="wholee1@googlemail.com"/> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="XXX">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/eshopProject/home.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/eshopProject/android.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
                    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    <?php  echo $pp_checkout_btn; ?>
                </form>


//added more php sources here
<?php
//if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page
if(isset($_POST['pid'])){
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$wasFound = false;
$i = 0;
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
    //if cart is empty or not set, run it
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
}
else{
    //if cart has at least one item in it
    foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item){
        $i++;
        while(list($key, $value) = each($each_item)){
            if($key =="item_id" && $value == $pid){
                //this item is in cart already, then it can be adjusted the quantity using array_splice()
                array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, 
                array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                $wasFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if($wasFound == false){
        array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    }
}
header("location: cart.php");
exit();
}
?>


//php code
    $pp_checkout_btn = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item){   
    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productId='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $category = $row["product_category"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $brand = $row["product_brand"];
            $price = $row["product_price"];
        }    
    $priceTotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
    $cartTotal = $priceTotal + $cartTotal;
    $x = $i + 1;
    //dynamic Checkout Button
    $pp_checkout_btn = '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$x.'" value="'.$product_name.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$x.'" value="'.$price.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$x.'" value="'.$each_item['quantity'].'">';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to increment the `$i` within foreach. That's why you generate only one item all the time (with `$x` equal to 1 all the time, all elements but the first one will be ignored).

I'd suggest replacing `$x = $i + 1;` with `$x = ++$i;`. Or just do `$i++` and the use `$i` instead of `$x` within the inputs' forming code.

Comment: still doesn't work. $i is number of array, then first array is 0, and next one is 1,2, and 3. I think it is right, but I don't know why it shown error. I was following this video:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDbTqeSUrQY&feature=relmfu

Comment: Could you log the final value of `$pp_checkout_btn` and show it here? (or pastebin it)